# Redirect Query String via .htaccess

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, redirect

I'm trying to redirect the user via the `.htaccess` file to create friendly  `URL` example:

UI URL: `https://example.com/courses/1`

htaccess role

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteRule ^courses/([0-9]{1})$ /courses.php?page=$1
```

Output URL: `https://example.com/courses.php?page=1`

And everything is working fine, Now I need to add other query params to the URL like this `http://smart-courses.com/courses/1?p1=1&p2=2` so, I need `htaccess` to redirect me to `https://example.com/courses.php?page=1&p1=1&p2=2`

I tried to create a new role to check if `p1` and `p2` are exists and rewrite the URL

```
RewriteRule ^courses/([0-9]{1,5})?lid=([0-9]{1,})&did=([0-9]{1,})$ /courses.php?page=$1&p1=$2&p1=$3
```

Also, I tried to take any chars after `([0-9]{1,5})` (page number) and put it after `?page=1` but it did not worked

```
RewriteRule ^courses/([0-9]{1})\?(.*)$ /courses.php?page=$1&$2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The query string is *not* part of the path section of the URL that the rule pattern is matched against. If you'd have to capture something from the query string you need to use a `RewritetCond`, that is documented. In this case however you don't even need to capture anything:

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteRule ^/?courses/(\d)$ /courses.php?page=$1 [QSA]
```

The `QSA` flag adds a potential query string to the (rewritten) target URL. The rewriting module takes care to use the correct concatenation here (the `&` character). Again, this behavior is documented: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_rewrite.html

Take a look yourself: [htaccess.madewithlove.com](https://htaccess.madewithlove.com?share=384e0435-1ace-4e16-b9a6-5e0a8b402f7b)

Comment: Thanks a lot, This role worked fine also I found this solution `^courses/([0-9]{1})$ /courses.php?page=$1&%{QUERY_STRING}`

Comment: Sure, that is _exactly_ what the `QSA` flag does.